# How to delegate ngFocus/ngBlur to directive's template <input> element?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, inputbox, dom-events

I'm trying to create a custom component (directive) which is composed of an `<input>` box and a `[-]` and `[+]` buttons. Currently, the example below only implements the input box.

So, say I have the following HTML for my directive:

`<my-input ng-blur="onBlur($event)" ng-focus="onFocus($event)"></my-input>`

And for testing purposes, I use this code:

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.onBlur = function ($event) {
    console.log('onBlur', $event);
  };

  $rootScope.onFocus = function ($event) {
    console.log('onFocus', $event);
  };
});
```

Now I want to create my custom `<my-input>` directive which has an `<input>` box on the template and I need the `ng-blur` and `ng-focus` set on `<my-input>` to respond to blur/focus events on the input box.

I have the following solution *almost* working: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpELmj

**1)** I have a feeling that this can be achieved in a much better way, I just can't seem to do it. Thoughts?

**2)** `$event` seems to be `undefined` and I can't understand why. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Ok figured it out.  Doron's answer was a good starting point for research, but now I think I have what you are looking for.  The key is you have to use `&` in the link section in order to get it to execute the expression.

```
.directive('myInput', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            blur: '&myBlur' //this is the key line
        },
        template: '<input ng-blur="blur($event)" ng-model="data">'
    }
})
```

This is how you use it:

```
<my-input my-blur="runBlurFunc()"></my-input>
```

If you really want to define the function on the root scope, you can use `$scope.$root.onBlur()` instead of `runBlurFunc()`

Answer (score 1):

Hope I got your question right, did you try to use the link function?

```
app.directive('myInput', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      ngBlur: '&',
      ngFocus: '&'
    },
    bindToController: true,
    controller: controllerFn,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    link:function(scope){

      scope.onBlur = function(ev){
        console.log(ev);
      }

      scope.onFocus = function(ev){
       console.log(ev);
     }

   },

   template: '[-]<input ng-blur="onBlur($event)" ng-focus="onFocus($event)"></input>[+]'
 }
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't, maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. With your solution your moving the `console.log`s to the directive implementation and I need that outside of that scope. I used the `run` block and `$rootScope` as example but it could also be some other controller. Basically, I want to delegate the `ng-focus` and `ng-blur` events to the directive parent scope.